# HTML2CANVAS cumulate canvas

Tags: html2canvas

Here is my problem.

I have a button who create the canvas of the capture of a div :

```
 $('#btn_share').live('click',function(){
    nomImage = $(this).data('titrevoyage');       
    html2canvas(document.querySelector("#container_global"),{useCORS: true, preferCanvas: true}).then(canvas => {  
        $('#popup_fb_share').stop().fadeIn();
        $('#popup_fb_share_overlay').stop().fadeIn();                        
        $('#image_to_share').html(canvas);            
        $('#share_download').live('click',function(){
            saveAs(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg"), nomImage+'.jpg');
        });
    });          
});
```

Here is the function to save the image :

```
function saveAs(uri, filename) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    if (typeof link.download === 'string') {
      link.href = uri;
      link.download = filename;

      //Firefox requires the link to be in the body
      document.body.appendChild(link);

      //simulate click
      link.click();

      //remove the link when done
      document.body.removeChild(link);
    } else {
      window.open(uri);
    }
}
```

The first time I click on #share_download it download perfectly my image
The second time, it download the old image and after it download the new one
The third time, it download the two firsts old images and after it download the new one
.....
.....

I trie to clear the canvas, to remove the canvas etc but it seems download all images each time.

The problem is not in the saveAs function because I console.log on the click on #share_download button and it console each images.

Do you know why ?

Thanks for your help.